# list to tree in typedracket

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to convert a list of integers to a tree. 
The following are my function definitions:

```
(define-struct (Some T)
  ([value : T]))

(define-type (Option T)
  (U 'None (Some T)))

(define-type BST (U 'E Nd))

(define-struct Nd
  ([root : Integer]
   [lsub : BST]
   [rsub : BST]))

(: bst-from-list ((Listof Integer) -> BST))
;; build a BST from a list of integers: use foldl to do s
(define (bst-from-list x)
(cond
    ('() 'E)
    ((cons hd _) (Nd hd 'E 'E))
    (else
  (foldl
```

I am learning from home and have no idea what to do after foldl. Can someone please help me?>

Answer (score 1):

[You already have an `(: insert : Integer BST -> BST)` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40519825/477476).
To build a tree with the elements 1, 2, 3, using `insert` you could write

```
(insert 3 (insert 2 (insert 1 'E)))
```

This is a left fold over `(1 2 3)` with `insert` as the function and `'E` as the initial value.
A left fold combines the first element with the initial value and then combines the result of that with the second element, and so on.

So all you need is

```
(: bst-from-list : ((Listof Integer) -> BST))
(define (bst-from-list ls)
  (foldl insert 'E ls))
```